# List a group a names to recall later in code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names that I need to filter a pivot table on. I use a Case Select to make the pivot items that are equal to the names visible and all other not visible. Can I make a one time array or list of these 15 names and call the list/array name within the code instead of using the 15 names in multiple locations? I have to fun a pivot table and sort on these names many times.

This is what I am trying to avoid. It works as is, but I'm trying to save myself headaches in the future with modifications.

```
Set table = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    With table.PivotFields("Assigned to")
        For Each PvI In .PivotItems
            Select Case PvI.Name
            Case "Antone", "Brad", "Cavan", "Chris", "Daneisha", "Edward", "James", "Jonathan", "Joesph", "Karen", "Shaun", "Steve", "Timothy", "Tracey"
                PvI.Visible = True
            Case Else
                PvI.Visible = False
            End Select
Next
End With
```

Comment: I would: store the list of values in a table in a worksheet somewhere, give that table a named range, and create a function that accepts a value as input and returns true/false if the input name is in the named range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `REVERSE` Select Case

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sNames As String

    sNames = "/Antone/Brad/Cavan/Chris/Daneisha/Edward/James/Jonathan/Joesph/Karen/Shaun/Steve/Timothy/Tracey/"

    Set Table = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

    With Table.PivotFields("Assigned to")
        For Each PvI In .PivotItems
            Select Case 0 '<~~ Reverse Select case
            Case InStr(1, sNames, "/" & PvI.Name & "/", vbTextCompare)
                PvI.Visible = False '<~~ This also reverses
            Case Else
                PvI.Visible = True
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is a simple way to see how `Reverse Select Case` works :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sNames As String, NameToCheck As String

    sNames = "/Antone/Brad/Cavan/Chris/Daneisha/Edward/James/Jonathan/Joesph/Karen/Shaun/Steve/Timothy/Tracey/"

    NameToCheck = "Antoneeeee"
    'NameToCheck = "Daneisha"

    Select Case 0
    Case InStr(1, sNames, "/" & NameToCheck & "/", vbTextCompare)
        MsgBox "Not found"
    Case Else
        MsgBox " Found"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does a Reverse Select Case provide any advantage over an If/Else structure when we're down to only one non-default case (as shown in your example)? I understand the benefit in staying close to the code the OP provided. Just wondering if it has, for example, a performance or reliability advantage in how the VBA interpreter executes the code.

Comment: Technically `Select Case` is faster than `IF/Else`. However the difference is very minute or you can say negligible in such a case. :) They both actually end up the same. You can use `IF/ELSEIF` in such a scenario. I was, like you said, staying close to what OP provided. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I figured they would be pretty close performance-wise in this case because with only one check the advantages of a jump table or hashing should be negligible or zero. I agree with staying close to OP. Actually our answers each kept one aspect and changed the other. You changed his Array request for a strong alternative but kept the switch case while I kept the Array idea but swapped out the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure and it eliminates the Select Case. I tested the code below minus the pivot table aspect. This stores your names in an array. You can keep the array as a global variable or as a range in the workbook (for the latter change the `nameArr = ...` line). The code `(UBound(Filter(nameArr, PvI.Name)) > -1)` will check if PvI.Name exists in nameArr by filtering the array for your desired name and checking if the resulting array has anything in it. Then the true/false value returned by the "array contains check" is assigned to `PvI.Visible`.

```
Dim nameArr As Variant
nameArr = Array("Antone", "Brad", "Cavan", "Chris", "Daneisha", "Edward", "James", "Jonathan", "Joesph", "Karen", "Shaun", "Steve", "Timothy", "Tracey")
Set table = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With table.PivotFields("Assigned to")
    For Each PvI In .PivotItems
        PvI.Visible = (UBound(Filter(nameArr, PvI.Name)) > -1)
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment, I recommend a table-driven approach.

The first thing to do is put the names of interest in a worksheet, and give that range a name. I called the range "MyNames" in this example.

The second thing to do is add this function to your project:

```
Function NameIsInList(LookFor As String) As Boolean
  On Error GoTo Err_NameIsInList
  NameIsInList = WorksheetFunction.Match(LookFor, Range("MyNames"), 0) > 0
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Function
Err_NameIsInList:
  ' the name was not found, or a bad parameter was supplied
  NameIsInList = False
  On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Finally, modify your procedure to use the function:

```
Set table = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
With table.PivotFields("Assigned to")
    For Each PvI In .PivotItems
        PvI.Visible = NameIsInList(PvI.Name)
    Next
End With
```

The advantages I was shooting for here are:

- Table-driven: The list of values can be stored in a worksheet where it's easily accessible and modified. (If you don't want users to see the LOV you can always hide the worksheet.)
- Reusable: Let the function do the work of checking the name list. You suggest this is something that needs to be done many times; the function can be called from multiple places.